# How to run a PETSc example?

Tags: petsc

I just installed the PETSc library.  This is what I did from the home directory ~

```
gunzip -c petsc-3.2-p6.tar.gz|tar -xof -
cd ~/petsc-3.2-p6
PETC_DIR=$PWD: export PETSC_DIR
./configure --download-f-blas-lapack=1
make all
make PETSC_DIR=/export/home/myusername/petsc-3.2-p6 PETSC_ARCH=arch-linux2-c-debug test
```

(note: I did not install mpich since it was already installed on the system)
Then, I tried to run an example from the following [this tutorial, slide 46 of 197](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/documentation/tutorials/UTAustinTutorial2011.pdf), which asks me to do the following:

```
cd ~/petsc-3.2-p6/src/snes/examples/tutorials
make ex5
```

In the process, I get the following errors:

```
makefile:24: /conf/variables: No such file or directory
makefile:24: /conf/rules: No such file or directory
makefile:24: /conf/test: No such file or directory
```

Is the problem in the way I setup PETSc? Or is there something I need to modify in the makefile?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You most likely haven't set the PETSC_DIR and PETSC_ARCH environment variables correctly.

For instance, you misspelled PETSC_DIR as PETC_DIR in the third line of your build example.

Comment: Sometimes, the simplest mistakes are often the hardest to see on your own! :)  Thanks for the help.  I got got it to work now.